# Group by and count query while showing all tables in textbox

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm kind of a newbie with ms access and sql. What I want to do is search for a Name in a table on the form and group by PersonID which is present in two tables while showing all of the attributes in table_1. Amount isn't an actual attribute in the original table, I wish to get it with count. The code I used was this:

```
Dim query As String

query = "Name LIKE '*" & Me.txtSearchName & "*' AND Name <> '0'"
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT PersonID, Name, Mail, City,
COUNT(*) AS Amount FROM Table 1 GROUP BY PersonID HAVING COUNT(*) >= 0"
Me.Filter = query
Me.FilterOn = True
```

**Table_1**

```
PersonID|Name  |Mail    |City   |Amount
1       |John  |j@.com  |A      |5
2       |Mark  |m@.com  |B      |2
3       |Lisa  |l@.com  |C      |4
```

The amount that is shown in the table is a count that counts the PersonID's in table_2.

**Table_2**

```
RestaurantID|PersonID|Date        |City   
1           |1       |23/05/2016  |X     
2           |2       |27/06/2015  |Y      
3           |2       |28/05/2016  |Y
```

I succeed with the searching but getting the Amount is a pain because I don't want all of the attributes in the group by. I tried:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM Table_1 t1, Table_2 t2
WHERE t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID)
GROUP BY t1.PersonID 
HAVING Count(*) >= 0
```

But it just doesn't work and keeps giving the error "Mail isn't part of an aggregate function" or some other attribute instead of Mail. I just want to count the restaurant visits of every PersonID.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do: update a form's recordsource or a textbox's value? Textboxes take one scalar value so how can you *show all tables in textbox*?

Comment: It is a continuous form so all records of the table can be shown in it. I simply wish to count for each personID in table_2 how many times it's in there and then have that amount shown on the form for each personID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `HAVING` clause, an `INNER JOIN` will filter all the rows where an `ID` in `Table_2` doesn't exists :

```
SELECT t1.PersonID, t1.Name, t1.Mail, t1.City,Count(*)
FROM Table_1 t1
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2
 ON (t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID)
GROUP BY t1.PersonID, t1.Name, t1.Mail, t1.City
```

Please avoid the use of implicit join syntax(comma separated) and use only the proper syntax of a join(like provided in my answer).

Comment: How do I bind the Count to a textbox? Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: You can save @sagi's query as a stored query (adding the `[Name] LIKE...` as `WHERE` condition) and use a [DLookUp](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php) in textbox. Do note queries can use form controls. Of course, give `Count(*)` a column alias.

Comment: This left out Person_ID's with 0 Restaurant visits. I decided to turn it into a Left Join so so it works like a charm now. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a DCount formula in new textbox on continuous form (bound to table_1) that counts PersonID in table_2 corresponding to the row record PersonID:

```
=DCount("*", "table_2", "PersonID=" & [PersonID])
```